# Is it "No band practice" or "No band practise" in British English?

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-roles

I understand that one is a noun and one is a verb. But is it correct to say "There is no band practice today" or "There is no band practise today"

**UPDATE:** I am not asking for the correct spelling of the word "practice" or "practise". The dictionary definition is clear. I am asking which usage is correct in this example sentence.

Comment: I've nominated a duplicate because the answers there answer this question. But there is also [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/practice) so the question would be closed anyway, I'm afraid.

Comment: Not duplicate. In that example "Practice amp" is clearly a noun. Thus the dictionary definition of the word provides a clear answer.

Comment: If *practice* is clearly a noun (an attributive noun, functioning as an adjective), then *practise* must be a verb. In your sentence, *band* is the attributive noun and *practice* the noun.